# Julia -- jupyter kernel dying in multithread when calling numpy

Tags: multithreading, numpy, julia

I have been having a problem with multithreading in Julia that I have managed to break down to the simple example:

The script

```
using PyCall, PyPlot
@pyimport numpy as np
N = 1000
a = np.zeros(N)
Threads.@threads for i in 1:length(a)
    #println("hello from thread ",Threads.threadid())
    a[i] = sin(i*pi/N)
end
plt.plot(a)
```

runs, whereas

```
using PyCall, PyPlot
@pyimport numpy as np
N = 1000
a = np.zeros(N)
Threads.@threads for i in 1:length(a)
    #println("hello from thread ",Threads.threadid())
    a[i] = np.sin(i*pi/N)
end
plt.plot(a)
```

does not. Instead the jupyter kernel dies. So apparently there is a problem using functions from pyimport inside of a parallel loop in Julia? The loop also runs well with numpy call in serial.

I am using jupyter lab on a redhat cluster. Using 32 threads. Running Julia 1.7.1

Comment: I think you should highlight that by "kernel" you refer to Jupyter, not some kernel function.

Comment: Thanks, I specified jupyter now

Comment: Python does not have multi-threads (openmp style) because GLI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython

Comment: Seems to be a known bug: https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl/issues/885

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the example to run in parallel by using Julia's distributed package instead of the threading.

Then

```
Using Distributed
N = 1000
a = np.zeros(N)
function sinmake(i)
    a[i] = np.sin(i*pi/N)
end
pmap(sinmake,1:N)
plt.plot(a)
```

It would be nice to be able to use python packages in thread-parallelism as well, but this solves my problem for now.

Comment: But... that code doesn't do anything treaded or distributed, at all. You just imported the package. Of course it works. Did you mean to use `pmap`?

Comment: You are right.. sorry I mean pmap